# How to record 1:1 (square) video with package camera in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I'm trying to record a video with flutter but in aspectRatio equals to 1. Here is my camera preview:

```dart
Transform.scale(
  scale: 1.0,
  child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: 1.0,
    child: OverflowBox(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: CameraPreview(controller!),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

And this is my record method when the user stops recording:

```dart
XFile? rawVideo =  await controller!.stopVideoRecording();

File file = File(rawVideo!.path);

int timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

String fileFormat = file.path.split('.').last;

_videoFile = await file.copy(
  '${directory.path}/$timestamp.$fileFormat',
);
```

But the video keeps recording in portrait 16:9 aspect ratio. How can I record in 1:1 ratio?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't with official camera plugin. You will have to crop the video post recording to get your desired result. Official camera plugin offers preset of resolutions if available on device.

For more info check out official documentation for `https://pub.dev/documentation/camera_platform_interface/latest/camera_platform_interface/ResolutionPreset.htmlResolutionPreset`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rahul. I'm trying a solution using ffmpeg to crop the video after the recording process. My issue now is to set the camera preview correctly in a square container.